# How can I vertically orient my text using SVG.js?

Tags: svg, svg.js

I have a vertical rectangle and I want to place a text inside it.

```
let draw = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%');
let rect;
let text;

rect = draw.rect(50, '100%').attr({
  fill: color,
  stroke: '#d9d9d9',
  'stroke-width': 1,
});
rect.move(50, 0);

text = draw.text('Some important text').font({ fill: '#ffffff' });
text.move(50, 0);
```

I tried to use `.rotate(90)` but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Set the text-orientation style to upright and the writing-mode style to vertical-lr to get vertical text.

In version 3 of svg.js the .style method becomes .css instead

```js
let draw = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%');
let rect;
let text;

rect = draw.rect(50, '100%').attr({
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: '#d9d9d9',
  'stroke-width': 1,
});
rect.move(50, 0);

text = draw.text('Some important text').font({ fill: '#ffffff' });
text.move(70, 0);
text.style({'text-orientation': 'upright', 'writing-mode': 'vertical-lr'})
```

```css
html, body, div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Comment: That's amazing Robert! Thanks so much.

Comment: In my case I only need the ```'writing-mode': 'vertical-lr'```. I believe that might be an alternative for having my right starting on the bottom and going up instead of up and down for the vertical right? I'll google it. Thanks man.